# Angular white page after injection service in constructor

Tags: angular

I'm having this issue that my web browser turns into white page after injecting my service into .ts constructor, If I remove it from constructor things turn into normal. even further I tried to do a routing and creating new components but same thing even routing doesn't work.
I don't know if this problem related wit hangular version. Any suggestion please.

**this is my service:**

```
 private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/relevebancaire';
  csvRecords: any;
  header: boolean = false;


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private ngxCsvParser: NgxCsvParser) { } @ViewChild('fileImportInput') fileImportInput: any;


  fileChangeListener($event: any): void {

    const files = $event.srcElement.files;
    this.header = (this.header as unknown as string) === 'true' || this.header;

    this.ngxCsvParser.parse(files[0], { header: this.header, delimiter: ';' })
    .pipe().subscribe({
      next: (result): void => {
        console.log('Result', result);
        this.csvRecords = result;
        let nLines = 0;
        for (let i = 0, n = this.csvRecords.length; i<n; ++i){
          if ( this.csvRecords[i] === '\n'){
            ++nLines;
          }
          console.log('Nombre de lignes: ', nLines);
        }

        for ( let u of this.csvRecords){
          if (u[10] === 'C'){
            console.log('Nombre des operation credit: ',u[10]);
          }
          else {
            console.log("does not have Operation Credit")
          }
          if (u[10] === 'D'){
            console.log('Nombre des operation debit: ',u[10]);
          }

        }

      },
      error: (error: NgxCSVParserError): void => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    });
  }


  getReleveBancaires(): Observable<ReleveBancaire[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      map((response: any) => response)
    );
  }

  postReleveBancaire( relevebancaire: ReleveBancaire) : Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<ReleveBancaire>(this.baseUrl,relevebancaire);
  }


}


interface GetResponse{
  response: {
    relevebancaire : ReleveBancaire[];
  }
```

**This is my component:**

```
relevebancaire!: ReleveBancaire[];
  lignereleve : LigneReleve[] = [];


  constructor(private ngxCsvParser: NgxCsvParser,
              public relevebancaireService: RelevebancaireService) {
  }
  csvRecords: any;
  header: boolean = false;

  fileChangeListener($event: any): void {

    const files = $event.srcElement.files;
    this.header = (this.header as unknown as string) === 'true' || this.header;

    this.ngxCsvParser.parse(files[0], {header: this.header, delimiter: ';'})
    .pipe().subscribe({
      next: (result): void => {
        // console.log('Result', result);
        this.csvRecords = result;
      },
      error: (error: NgxCSVParserError): void => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    });
  }


  releveBancaires()
  {
    this.relevebancaireService.getReleveBancaires().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.relevebancaire = data;
        // console.log("showing data from MySQL", data);
      }
    )
  }
```

**This is my homepage without injecting the service in constructor :**

[image]

Comment: Any issues in console?

Comment: no nothing, eveything is compiling successfully

Comment: check whether u have given providedIn:root or imported your service file in providers of module file

Comment: Hey Mohammed I just solved this HttpClientModule was not presented in imports you just gave me a hint about providers and that came out on my mind, Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome.